# Is it possible to change the STMP port from 587 to 2525?

Tags: smtp, mandrill

I'm deploying an app on Google Compute Engine (GCE) instance, with send email features, using mandrill as my email server. GCE blocks ports 25, 465, and 587 except for service partners (Sendgrid). When configuring mandrill only port 587 is setted. Is it possible to configure a different port on mandrill such as 2525?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mandrill supports several other ports besides 587, as shown in the [documentation here](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21738477-What-SMTP-ports-can-I-use-). You don't need to change anything in your account, just select which port and encryption you want to use in your code/configuration.

Comment: Heya @kaitlin-mandrill. Just tried it out and it worked. Thank you for the quick reply. Cheers.