# use different outgoing port for smtp server

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-compute-engine

While setting-up smtp server using smtplib on Python, you get the option to specify hostname and port. But those correspond to the remote host I am sending mail to. And there are other similar questions for this.

I want to change the underlying port, that smtplib will use to send the mail.
I want to change it from 25 to something else as the Google Cloud Platform instance I am using has blocked 25.

Please don't suggest using third party services like sendgrid.
And also I didn't find these answers useful

[1](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449039/google-cloud-server-mail-instance)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465869/is-it-possible-to-change-the-stmp-port-from-587-to-2525)

Comment: I'd be very careful about trying to handle email on a server that's configured to make it difficult. Usually they're doing that to prevent their system from being used to send spam, and if you find a way around the block, you're probably violating their terms of service and they may shut you down.

Comment: "the underlying port" ... do you mean the local port for the connection? `smtplib` uses a dynamically assigned port for the local address, not port 25. I setup an SMTP session and printed `connection.sock`, it is `<socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('192.168.0.7', 52834), raddr=('166.70.12.10', 25)>`.  notice it used local port 52834.